# web2py request.post_vars missing in HTTP PATCH

Tags: rest, web2py

I'm looking to make use of HTTP PATCH to update a single field in a record (distinguishing this from PUT which should update the entire record). However it appears that post_vars (which I plan to hold the updated fields) does not get parsed in the request object due to this line in parse_post_vars in gluon/globals.py:

```
and env.request_method in ('POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'BOTH')):
```

Is there a reason that we don't have PATCH in that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, `request.post_vars` is intended to be a dictionary-like object (derived from form data or JSON), but a patch document need not be. For example, if you send a patch of type `application/json-patch+json` as described [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#page-3), the resulting Python object would be a list.

Because the format of patch documents is flexible, you should handle parsing and applying them on your own. You can always read the patch document directly via `request.body.read()`.

I suppose web2py could automatically parse a patch document of type `application/merge-patch+json` (as described [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396)). Feel free to post to the [developer's list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/web2py-developers) about that possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will likely just parse it myself.